Systematic Way to Identify Through Azure UI Required "App Registration" API Permission
Ok, I have this code (snippet) that is responsible for starting a VM:
var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithSubscription(data.SubscriptionId);

var vm = await azure.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroupAsync("YourResourceGroupName", data.VmName);

if (vm == null)
{
    return new NotFoundObjectResult($"VM with name {data.VmName} not found");
}

await vm.StartAsync();

I run it from a Azure function, it fails:

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: StartVM.
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent: The client 'XXX' with
object id 'XXX' does not have authorization to perform action
'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' over scope
'/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/YourResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/XXX'
or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
refresh your credentials.

Fair... as I haven't added that permission to my Azure "App Registration", so I go there:

An honestly, I have not idea where to find this, I've clicked through most of them. I've faced this issue several times so my question is, is there a easy way on the Azure UI or programmatically to go from the permission path stated in the error to adding it in the UI?

Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read

Corresponds to which category in the UI and which subcategory, and how do I determine that in a generic sense in the future (with the next permissions error)?

Note that, you need to assign Azure RBAC roles to service principal, which are different from "App registration" API permissions while working with Azure resources.

Hi @DavidRogers Any update?

I assigned "Desktop Virtualization Power On Contributor" to the entire subscription and updated "YourResourceGroupName" to my actual resource group, seems to work :)

The error occurs if the service principal does not have proper permissions or roles to perform the operation.
I have one Azure VM named srivm which is in "Stopped" state as below:

Initially, I too got same error when I tried to start the VM by authenticating with service principal not having any Azure RBAC roles under VM:

To find which Azure RBAC role has 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read or other permissions, you can refer this Azure built-in roles for Compute document:

In my case, I assigned "Virtual Machine Contributor" role to service principal under Azure VM:

After assigning the role, I ran below sample code and got response like this:
using Azure.Core;
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;

namespace StartVM
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new StartVmData
            {
                SubscriptionId = "subId",
                ResourceGroupName = "rgname",
                VmName = "vmname",
                ClientId = "appId",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                TenantId = "tenantId"
            };

            await StartVirtualMachineAsync(data);
        }

        public static async Task StartVirtualMachineAsync(StartVmData data)
        {
            try
            {
                var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(data.TenantId, data.ClientId, data.ClientSecret);
                var armClient = new ArmClient(credential, data.SubscriptionId);
                var resourceGroup = armClient.GetResourceGroupResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{data.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{data.ResourceGroupName}"));
                var vm = await resourceGroup.GetVirtualMachineAsync(data.VmName);

                if (vm == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"VM with name {data.VmName} not found.");
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Starting VM {data.VmName}...");
                var operation = await vm.Value.PowerOnAsync(WaitUntil.Completed);
                Console.WriteLine($"VM {data.VmName} has been started successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class StartVmData
    {
        public string SubscriptionId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string ResourceGroupName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string VmName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string ClientId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string TenantId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where VM started successfully as below:

Note that, API permissions are required when you are working with tenant level Microsoft APIs like Microsoft Graph, SharePoint, Power BI etc...
While working with subscription-level Azure resources, you must assign Azure RBAC roles to the user or service principal under scopes like subscription, resource group or resource level.
